# System.Text.JSON.DeserializeAsync JSON Objects as shown my code is not happening properly

Tags: .net, json, stream, deserialization, system.text.json

I am using the following data model and code to asynchronously deserialize some JSON, however the root model's property is not being read in properly.  How can this be fixed?

The data model:

```vb
Namespace TestData
    Public Class IDocsAttribute
        Public Property Project_No As String
        Public Property Project_Name As String
        Public Property Deliverable As String
        Public Property Doc_ID As String
        Public Property Doc_No As String
        Public Property Title As String
        Public Property Doc_Type As String
        Public Property Revision As String
        Public Property Issue_State As String
        Public Property FileName As String
        Public Property Supplier_Doc_No As String
        Public Property Supplier_Name As String
        Public Property Originator_RE_Name As String
        Public Property Supplier_Revision As String
        Public Property Return_Date As String
        Public Property Tag_Equipment_No As String
        Public Property Doc_Classification As String
        Public Property SDR_Code As String
        Public Property URL As String
        Public Property Folder_No As String
        Public Property Rev_Ver As String
        Public Property Cur_Ver As String
        Public Property Discipline As String
        Public Property Requisition_PO_No As String
    End Class

    Public Class Root
        Public Property Children As List(Of IDocsAttribute)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The deserialization code:

```vb
Private Async Sub IsAvailiable_ClickAsync(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IsAvailiable.Click
    Try
        Dim oContent1 = New StringContent("")
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("check/", oContent1)
        Dim sReponse As String
        If (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) Then
            sReponse = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        Else
            sReponse = "Failed"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim squote = Chr(34).ToString()
        Dim sbody As String = Requestmessage

        Dim content = New StringContent(sbody)
        response = Await client.PostAsync("document/", content)
        sReponse = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

        Using stream As IO.Stream = Await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()                
            Dim filemodules As Root = Await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(Of Root)(stream)
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

JSON Format shown below for which deserialization is happening:

```json
{
   "iDocs_Attribute" : [
     {
      "Project_No" : "236910",
      "Project_Name" : "236910",
      "Deliverable" : "Yes",
      "Doc_ID" : "239585832",
      "Doc_No" : "236910-BAY3-CMC-13101-01-00006",
      "Title" : "E1-E6-22001-01",
      "Doc_Type" : "Supplier Document",
      "Revision" : "1",
      "Issue_State" : "C1-Accepted without Comments",
      "Discipline" : "23.1 - Civil Structural",
      "FileName" : "236910-BAY3-CMC-13101-01-00006.PDF",
      "Supplier_Doc_No" : "1923401907PD-BBS\n-1",
      "Requisition_PO_No" : "CMC-13101-01",
      "Supplier_Name" : "CMC Rebar",
      "Originator_RE_Name" : "Jorge Manrique",
      "Supplier_Revision" : "01",
      "Received_Date" : "11/07/2019",
      "Return_Date" : "11/07/2019",
      "Tag_Equipment_No" : "NO-TAGS",
      "Doc_Classification" : "S2 - Secondary 2",
      "SDR_Code" : "G82 Placing/Marking Drawings and Bar Bending Schedules",
      "URL" : "https://edms-tst.mcdermott.com/edms/redirect/getdocumentf?spec=0,1,239585832,6,0,557173022",
      "Folder_No" : "G - Detail Drawings",
      "Rev_Ver" : "6",
      "Cur_Ver" : "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please, spend some time to properly format code in question

Comment: Sorry for that . Will definetly do that apology

Comment: The name of the root property should be `iDocs_Attribute` not `Children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two problems here.

**Firstly**, your root JSON property is named `iDocs_Attribute` not `Children`:

```
{
   "iDocs_Attribute" : [/* Contents omitted */]
}
```

Therefore the corresponding vb.net property must have the same name:

```vb
Public Class Root
    Public Property iDocs_Attribute As List(Of IDocsAttribute)
End Class
```

Alternatively, you could apply [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to inform the serializer of the correct name:

```vb
Public Class Root
    <System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("iDocs_Attribute")> _
    Public Property Children As List(Of IDocsAttribute)
End Class
```

**Secondly**, your deserialization code reads from the `response.Content` *twice*:

```vb
' Reads the response as a string
sReponse = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() 

' Reads the response as a Stream
Using stream As IO.Stream = Await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()                
    Dim filemodules As Root = Await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(Of Root)(stream)
End Using
```

I suspect you should only do one or the other, but not both.  If you want to use async deserialization, remove the second call to `Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.